# How can I pass the current theme of the app into StyleSheet.create()?

Tags: react-native

Due to various limitations, I cannot store the current theme in props. I have to use a custom props that I cannot modify at the moment. I have been able to get around this by using React Context to store the current theme.

I have a class called pageStyle. In it, I have a pageContainer that I'd like to be able to set backgroundColor either to dark or light values.

I am able to get the current theme in a separate class R by using this.context.theme. R is also where I am rendering the FlatList object and passing `style={pageStyle.pageContainer}`.

I could create two separate pageContainers, called pageContainerDark and pageContainerLight, and have the correct respective backgroundColors for both. However, this feels messy to me. This would also require having a method for each style page to determine which pageContainer to use and is not scalable whatsoever. I have also tried using a global variable but was having some issues with this.

Is there a cleaner way to set pageContainer's backgroundColor based on the current theme?

I have attached the pageStyle.ts file below.

```
//pageStyle.ts

import { StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const pageStyles =  StyleSheet.create({
    pageContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#232323"
    },
    // pageContainerDark: {
    //     flex: 1,
    //     backgroundColor: "#232323"
    // },
    // pageContainerLight: {
    //     flex: 1,
    //     backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    // },
    pageContentContainer: {
        paddingBottom: 0
    }
});

// export function getPageContainerFromPageStyles(theme: string) {
//   if (theme == 'light') {
//     return pageStyle.pageContainerForLightTheme
//   } else {
//     return pageStyle.pageContainerForDarkTheme
//   }
// }

export { pageStyle };
```

Comment: Could you please tell what was the issue of global variable?

Comment: @NaeimFard I created a new file called global.ts (all of the files are typescript). All that was in this file was `export default {}`. I imported this file in my other files to either set global.theme to a value or to grab the global.theme. global.theme was set to the correct theme value in the file I set it, but when I tried to get the value of global.theme in other files, it wasn't actually set globally for some reason. It was also giving me a compile error of `Property 'theme' does not exist on type '{}'.`